# View file in project view Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have started using Intellij and I am trying to find a feature that was in eclipse.  I often navigate to a file either through the code or through a CTRL-N search.  When I have the file I found open, I want to see which project and which folder of the project the file is in.  I found a way to open the file in Windows Explorer which tells me what I want but I would rather stay in intellij and see the folders on the left expanded to the location of the file. Does this exist in intellij?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the heading of Project Explorer panel their will be a circle with 4 lines inside it.
Press that it will take you to the place where you file is inside the project

*Image upload not working thats why explaination*